# What are the purpose and benefits of using persistent connection in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, persistent-connection

According to php manual:

> Persistent connections are not closed at the end of the script, but are cached and re-used when another script requests a connection using the same credentials. The persistent connection cache allows you to avoid the overhead of establishing a new connection every time a script needs to talk to a database, resulting in a faster web application.

One advantage is efficiency that we do not need to make connection each time script executes. What are other advantages of persistent connection? Like query cache etc?

Comment: [Mysql persistent connections and advantages of mysql_pconnect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1128329/6521116)

Comment: Mostly the disadvantages are mentioned in most articles. According to php manual :" In fact, to be extremely clear about the subject, persistent connections don't give you any functionality that wasn't possible with their non-persistent brothers."

Comment: To reduce the delay caused by establishing connectivity between two servers by preventing the connection from closing and needing to be renegotiated. Such as when connected to a distant or heavily trafficked server. Otherwise none.

Comment: It seems that it can only be used to reduce time consumed in establishing connection. I couldn't find any other benefit.

Comment: My earlier experiences (legacy mysql extension around the mid 2000's) were awful: PHP was actually unable to reuse existing connections, God knows why, and I eventually exhaused the connection limit. I hope that the mysqli in 2017 has fixed that. In any case, unlike with other database engines, MySQL connections happen really fast so potential benefit is not as promising.

Answer (score 1):

it Allows for resumption of transactions across multiple request as well as Allow connections setting such as character set encoding to persist

Comment: Yes, may be it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965761/working-with-mysqli-ini-set